# How to select json array items with jq where a constant string ends with the array item?

Tags: jq

Given a JSON:

```json
{
    "HostedZones": [
        {
            "Id": "/hostedzone/AAAA",
            "Name": "example.com."
        },
        {
            "Id": "/hostedzone/BBBB",
            "Name": "local."
        },
        {
            "Id": "/hostedzone/CCCC",
            "Name": "internal.example.com."
        },
        {
            "Id": "/hostedzone/DDDD",
            "Name": "public.example.com."
        }
    ]
}
```

And a string constant: `test.internal.example.com.`.

I want to select array items where the string constant ends with the `.Name` value, resulting in this output:

```json
[
    {
        "Id": "/hostedzone/AAAA",
        "Name": "example.com."
    },
    {
        "Id": "/hostedzone/CCCC",
        "Name": "internal.example.com."
    }
]
```

Is there a way to achieve this with `jq`?

I've tried using the `endswith` operator in `jq`, but it doesn't work:

```
[.HostedZones[] | select($myconst | endswith("." + .Name))]
```

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:105): Cannot index string with string "Name"
```

I believe the issue here is that `.Name` is applied to `$myconst`, not the array items, but I don't know how to swap the operands of `endswith`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch the context between the item and your constant (`endswith` requires the full string as input, and the partial string as argument).

```bash
jq --arg myconst "test.internal.example.com." '
  .HostedZones | map(select(.Name as $name | $myconst | endswith($name)))
'
```

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "/hostedzone/AAAA",
    "Name": "example.com."
  },
  {
    "Id": "/hostedzone/CCCC",
    "Name": "internal.example.com."
  }
]
```